# Is it possible to create a formula that checks certain cells in a row against a lookup list and returns true/false value?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, match, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

[Here's](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p_XHWDDdIrMx7dCx1mk1-nPmR1IMKoRX4KUz2AtIwiY/edit?usp=sharing) a link to the spreadsheet for context. Essentially, here's what I'm trying to accomplish: In the tab titled 'Detailed Learning Report', I want column K to read "Complete" or "Incomplete" based on criteria. So, for example, for row 2, I want to check which site the UID is connected to and, depending on if it's Bedford, San Bernardino or Lithonia, determine if that user completed all required courses for that site. I have a breakdown of which courses are required per site on the tab titled 'Sheet 3'. Ultimately, at the end of this, I want a unique list of users (that's the unique list you see on the 'Sheet 3') and either "Complete" if all the required courses are marked completed in the 'Detailed Learning Report' tab or "Incomplete" if not. I'm not even sure if this is possible so I appreciate your help!

Comment: Try posting it in superuser if it does not concern any coding

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(E2:E="",,
 IF((E2:E="BEDFORD PARK IL")*
    (H2:H="COMPLETE")*
    ((F2:F=Sheet3!I2)+
     (F2:F=Sheet3!I3)+
     (F2:F=Sheet3!I4)+
     (F2:F=Sheet3!I5)), "COMPLETE",
 IF((E2:E="SAN BERNARDINO CA")*
    (H2:H="COMPLETE")*
    ((F2:F=Sheet3!I5)+
     (F2:F=Sheet3!I7)+
     (F2:F=Sheet3!I8)), "COMPLETE", "INCOMPLETE"))))
```

[image]

```
((F2:F=Sheet3!I2)+
 (F2:F=Sheet3!I3)+
 (F2:F=Sheet3!I4)+
 (F2:F=Sheet3!I5))
```

can be shortened to:

```
(REGEXMATCH(F2:F, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, Sheet3!I2:I5)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Apologies, I forgot to include a piece of this puzzle. I also need the formula to identify the UID and determine if that particular user completed all the required courses listed on Sheet 3. It looks like the formula is just replicating column H. I appreciate your time!